# How to resize an image in a content type

Tags: theming, media

I created an article and added an image field, but I don't know how to resize the image. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use image styles for this. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/article/display` and change the respective image style you want to use for the image field under 'format'.

[image]

If the available image styles don't suit your need, then you can go to `admin/config/media/image-styles/add` and add new image style you want. For more information on using image styles, refer image documentation at https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/image

Answer (score 0):

[Image Resize Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter)

> The easiest end-user solution for resizing inline images.
>
> This filter makes it easy to resize images, especially when combined
>   with a WYSIWYG editor such as tinyMCE, CKeditor etc. Users never have
>   to worry about scaling image sizes again, just insert an image and set
>   it's height and width properties in HTML (this is done automatically
>   by WYSIWYG editors) and the image is resized on output to match the
>   HTML.